# ftp upload not working

Tags: php

File is not uploading to FTP and errors: **Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Can't open that file: No such file or directory coming**. We are using following code:

```
    $server = 'ftp.domain.com';
$ftp_user_name = 'upload@domain.com';
$ftp_user_pass = 'password';
$dest = 'files/test.txt';
$source = 'test.txt';
$src = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir");

$connection = ftp_connect($server);
$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }
$upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, FTP_BINARY);
if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }
ftp_close($connection);
```

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the server? ( Tough it should have told you it's a permission issue once I had a similar issue and got it solved with a simple chmod )

Comment: Does the `files` directory exist on the remote?

Comment: Does test.txt exist in the script's working directory? Looks like it can't find the file on your server that it should be uploading.

Comment: yes files exist and chmod to 777

Answer (score 28):

Here's an answer from the comments of php.net on ftp_put:

---

Found the prob, you can't put a path to the destination file
(even though I can do that in the dos ftp client...?)

e.g. - this doesn't work

```
ftp_put($conn, '/www/site/file.html','c:/wamp/www/site/file.html',FTP_BINARY);
```

you have to put

```
ftp_chdir($conn, '/www/site/');
ftp_put($conn,'file.html', 'c:/wamp/www/site/file.html', FTP_BINARY );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. Solved that trouble for me. Tahnks! :)

Comment: FTP_BINARY did it for me!  I had FTP_ASCII in there which wasn't uploading images properly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I solved it using [ftp_nb_put()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-put.php). Same function but it allows your program to run more connections or something:-)